# Resultado no esperado con join en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, join

Este script se comporta según lo esperado.

```
<script>
    let cadena = "soy una cadena";
    let cadenaI = cadena.split("").join("/");       
    console.log("soy cadenaI: "+cadenaI);
</script>
```

Este segundo script no se ejecuta según lo esperado, siendo aparentemente lo mismo:

```
<script>
    let cadena2 = "soy una cadena";
    let cadena2I = cadena.split("");
    cadena2I.join("/");
    console.log("soy cadena2I: "+cadena2I);
</script>
```

Comment: No olvides [edit] tu pregunta explicando cuál es el resultado esperado, y cuál es el obtenido. Además, pon en el título el problema en cuestión. Lee [ask].

Comment: Tal parece que usas el nombre equivocado de variable. Debería ser `let cadena2I = cadena2.slpit("");`. Te hace falta el número `2` al final de `cadena`.

Comment: La variable cadenaI del primer script, es una cadena de texto, en cambio en el segundo ejemplo, la variable cadena2I es un array por eso no se comporta igual aunque se parezcan por código.

Yo lo arreglaría poniendo una tercera variable en el segundo script con algo cómo: 
cadena3I = cadena2I[0].join("/");
console.log("soy cadena3i"+cadena3I);

Comment: La pregunta es interesante pero tiene su respuesta fácil ya que es una simple cuestión de asignación errónea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estás guardando en ninguna variable el resultado de la operación join, con lo que estás mostrando en consola el resultado del split. Guarda el resultado en una nueva variable y podrás mostrarla.